# Como atualizar select com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Olá.

Tenho um select

```
<div class="seletor">
   <select name="numeros" id="numeros">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
   </select>
   <span class="custom-select">1</span>
</div>
```

E queria saber como faço para selecionar outro valor utilizando jQuery?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Assim nesse select esta seleciona a opção 1 certo? E preciso selecionar outra opção utilizando jQuery. Tentei $("#numeros").val("1"); mas não deu certo

Comment: Coloquei na resposta, ve se é o que precisa :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `.val()` diretamente no select:

```js
$('#selectValue').click(function (){ 
  $('#numeros').val($('#valor').val());
  $('.custom-select').text($('#numeros').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seletor">
   <select name="numeros" id="numeros">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
   </select>
   <span class="custom-select">1</span>
</div>
<br>
Digite o valor: <input type="text" id="valor">
<input type="button" id="selectValue" value="Selecionar" /><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select option[value="2"]').attr({ selected : "selected"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```